# DocumentFormat.OpenXml 2.20.0 -does it work on .net 7 on linux?

Tags: .net, linux, openxml, .net-7.0

I'm wondering if DocumentFormat.OpenXml 2.20.0 will be working on .net7 on linux machine.

Comment: What's the *actual* question? Very few people use the low-level OpenXML SDK directly, they use high level libraries like EPPlus, ClosedXML or NPOI to create Excel files from data in about 10 lines. If you want to create Excel files, use one of these libraries. As for your actual question, did you check the package's [NuGet page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/#supportedframeworks-body-tab)? If it's .NET Core or Standard, it works on Linux